# My React-Firebase app is slow, how to make it faster

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a React-Firebase app, and the whole app was running smoothly. The authentication, the creating, logging in and logging out of the app was all very fast. Once I started to create links to the firestore, it became very slow. I have used Firebase before in instant messaging apps and it was very fast, but for some reason, it isn't anymore.

Here is the file that is causing the app to be slow:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat'
import { db } from '../firebase.js'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import './styles/MasterScreen.css'

const MasterScreen = ({typeOfUser}) => {
    const [customer, setCustomers] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            await firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                setCustomers(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()).filter(doc => doc.typeOfUser === 'customer'))
            })
        }
        fetchData()
    })

    async function changeState(uid, state) {
        // await db.collection('users').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        //     snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().uid === uid && db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).update({state}))
        // })
        const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').get()
        snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().uid === uid && firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).update({state}))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar typeOfUser={typeOfUser} />
            <div className="customers">
                {customers.map(e => (
                    <div key={e.uid} className="customer">
                        <div className={`state ${e.state === 'go' ? 'green' : e.state === 'slow' ? 'yellow' : e.state === 'stop' ? 'red' : 'pause'}`}>
                            <h3>CURRENT STATE</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="customerContents">
                            <button className='goOne btn' onClick={() => changeState(e.uid, 'go')}>GO</button>
                            <button className='slowOne btn' onClick={() => changeState(e.uid, 'slow')}>SLOW</button>
                            <button className='stopOne btn' onClick={() => changeState(e.uid, 'stop')}>STOP</button>
                            <button className='pauseOne btn' onClick={() => changeState(e.uid, 'pause')}>PAUSE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MasterScreen
```

My logic is to go inside each document in the collection and find the doc that has the same uid as the one given. Then upload the 'state' of the user to Firebase. I tried removing onSnapshot to make it faster.

If you could help, that would be create!

Comment: Could you specify how much time it takes to query from Firestore and add the structure of your database?

Comment: Anywhere from 10-30 seconds, sometimes more if I click multiple components at once.

Comment: can you also add your database scheme and explain why you are using exactly this approach? Maybe it would be faster to get all docs from a collection and sort them out. It should be also more cost efficient